# How do I avoid tearout when planing end-grain?

Tags: plane, end-grain, hand-planing, community-project, tolerance

I am making [a birdhouse](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218/community-project-lets-make-a-birdhouse) and wanted to ensure that the two sloped sides of the box were the same height so the top flap would sit flat on both sides.  I grabbed a block plane to do this and had really horrible tear-out.  Thankfully,  I was able to rip the oops mostly off and finished the job with a sander, but I feel like this is something I **should** be able to do with a block plane, but maybe my technique was wrong.

Is there a way to plane on an end grain that will eliminate tear-out, or is it a universally bad idea and one should go for the sanding pad instead?

Comment: How long was the surface you were planing?

Comment: Short, approximately 6" or so.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/741/how-do-you-plane-end-grain. Although the other question doesn't explicitly mention tearout, it falls under the question of "gotchas" and is covered in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Everything I've read says you need to clamp a waste block on the end of your board to prevent the tear out.  It is even recommended to do this if you are using a router or jointer.

By keeping the pressure on with a waste block it won't be able to splinter down the board.[image]

[Source](https://www.fine-tools.com/G307910.html)

Of course the other option would be to plane toward the center from both sides.

Answer (score 5):

- plane inwards from edges.
- chamfer the far edge and angle the plane.
- support the edge with sacrificial wood.
- use a shooting board.

Comment: Was able to look up what a shooting board was but having an issue trying to figure out what "_chamber the far edge and angle the plane_" means

Comment: @Matt I think he meant Chamfer, so I changed it

Comment: @matt: bowlturner is right, I'm posting from a phone - auto(in)correct!

Comment: I realize this is a closed question but it may be worth a comment for future responses. To prevent people from having to look up terminology, I consider it a good practice to define uncommon terms in the answer, such as a shooting board (possibly a chamfer, but I think that's a common enough term to not need it.)

Comment: @DanielB. or better yet, open a new question and cross-link the answer and newly-spawned question.