Recommendation on making a shoe rack
First project - Trying to take up woodworking as a hobby and was confused with all the information available. Please be gentle.
I am trying to make a simple shoe rack that will be minimally used and kept inside the house. I have built the structure on SketchUp (in the spirit of learning the tool) and am ready to start.
Questions -

What type of wood should I use? - I am planning to use pine wood from Home Depot and paint the entire structure after building with the beyond paint. Is there a recommendation on another wood? and the finish process?

What tools are a must? - Among the power tools, I was thinking JigSaw (to cut some shape) and a circular saw (to cut the boards in size). I don't even have a working table yet, so would be cutting everything on the floor.


Any help/suggestions are appreciated!!

Welcome. These are fairly broad questions, which don’t exactly lend themselves to this format. Couple of things: please identify what you’ve already researched, so that we might be more focused with our advice. The second question is mostly answerable by opinion, which also doesn’t work well here.

You might want to post the image of your project, so viewers have a better handle on it.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. In order for your Q to survive review it would need to be trimmed down as 1 and 2 are completely separate queries. However, neither is really suitable for the SE format as asked. 1 is very subjective, but is easily covered by a single sentence — you can use pretty much anything you can buy easily! Not basla :-) but construction wood (2x material, or "SPF"), actual pine, poplar, birch, soft maple, beech, oak, ash, etc. etc. Even just plywood. And additionally 2 is really far too broad as well as being subjective, because an absolute bare-bones tool set.... [contd]

...for one person will include tools that are entirely missing from someone else's must-haves list. But again there's good news as there's plenty of existing help on this basic topic online. A good handful of my favourite YouTubers whose content is geared to beginners and learners — including Stumpy Nubs, Rex Kruger, wortheffort, Frank's Workbench — have one or more videos that cover this. Additionally we have a previous Q&A that I think covers it quite well https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-started-with-limited-funds-and-space/

Additional ground-up advice can be found in the following two Q&As: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/how-do-i-know-what-tools-i-need and https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/one-day-projects-for-wood-working-fundamentals
